# Python regex to remove string which may contain additional character

Tags: python, string, replace

I've got a string in python that sometimes starts with either `{txt -` or `{txt`.

These do not always appear at the start of the string, but if they do, I want to remove them.

I know I can do it like this:

```
string = string.strip('{txt -').strip('{txt')
```

But I'm thinking there is surely a better solution (maybe using regex). Is it possible to add a potential extra character to a regex (in this case `-`)?

Comment: What's the point of your `strip('{txt')`? It doesn't strip anything that wasn't already stripped by the `strip('{txt -')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with `( -)?` for an optional space and hyphen.

```py
re.sub('^{txt( -)?', '', string)
```

Note that `strip` does not work like you think it does. For instance, `"t".strip("{txt")` produces an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need some function to only return the word and strip/erase any other character in your string:

You could try something like this:

```
def remove_special_chars(text, remove_digits:bool=False):

    if remove_digits:
        text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z ]", '', text)
    else:
        text = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", '', text)
    

    return text
```